# Can google apps script identify emails with the '+' tags?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Does google apps script allow for handling specific gmail addresses with a '+' tag/extension in the address? I have a script to take graphic attachments and move them to a drive folder and would like to focus it to specific tags.

Comment: I search documentation for Gmail Tags.  Nothing made sense.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use Regex with `match`

Using this sample function:

```js
function getPlusMails() {
  // get all inbox threads
  let threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads()
  
  // initializing the output array
  let messagesFromPlus = []

  // for each thread in inbov
  let messages = threads.forEach(t => {
    // get the messages
    let _messages = t.getMessages()
    // for each message in thread
    _messages = _messages.forEach(m => {
      // check if sender has + in address, if so, add to output array
      if (m.getFrom().match(/\+/)) messagesFromPlus.push(m)
    })
  })

  return messagesFromPlus
}
```

You can get a list of all the messages for which the sender has an address with `+` in it.

#### How it works

It uses the native JavaScript `string.match()` to see if a message sender address has a `+` in it.

```
if ( message.getFrom().match(/\+/) )
```

This will return `true` if there is a `+` and `false` if not. In the function above, all the threads in the inbox are queried, although you can narrow this down if you want, via search queries. Then every message in each thread is checked. If the sender address contains a `+` then it is appended onto a list `messagesFromPlus`.

You can call this from another function and then go through each message doing what you need to do with them.

#### References

- [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)
- [Match](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)